# how to add external Emacs config files to Git repository?

Tags: git, emacs, github, symlink

I use Aquamacs Emacs and GitHub on OSX. I'm trying to add my Emacs config files to my Git repository for my Emacs files.

My Git repository for my Emacs files lives at `~/elisp/`

I have Emacs config files in two other places:
1. a file: `~/.emacs`
2. a directory: `~/Library/Application Support/Aquamacs\ Emacs`

I tried moving the file and the directory into `~/elisp` so I can track them in Git, then using symlinks to restore them to their original location virtually.

From inside my `~/elisp` directory, I did this:

```
mv .emacs elisp/.emacs
ln -s elisp/.emacs .emacs
mv Aquamacs\ Emacs ~/elisp/Aquamacs\ Emacs
ln -sf ~/elisp/Aquamacs\ Emacs ~/Library/Application\ Support/Aquamacs\ Emacs
```

This appeared to work and Emacs seems to be running correctly.

However, now I'm having trouble committing the directory to the repository:

```
~/elisp/ git:(master) $ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   Aquamacs Emacs (modified content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

~/elisp/ git:(master) $ git add .

~/elisp/ git:(master) $ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   Aquamacs Emacs (modified content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

~/elisp/ git:(master) $ git add Aquamacs\ Emacs

~/elisp/ git:(master) $ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   Aquamacs Emacs (modified content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

~/elisp/ git:(master) $ git commit -m "moved folder"
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   Aquamacs Emacs (modified content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: did you try `git add --all`?

Comment: Yes, same message. 
`$ git add --all`  
`$ git commit -m "moved folder"`  
`# On branch master`  
`# Changes not staged for commit:`  
`#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)`  
`#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)`  
`#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)`  
`#`  
`# modified:   Aquamacs Emacs (modified content)`  
`#`  
`no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")`

Comment: In the output appears nothing about `.emacs`. It seems the problem is in the other folder. Do you have the application opened? may be some files are constantly changing

Comment: This is a complicated setup. Any reason why you don't just put everything in `~/.emacs.d` and `git init` that folder?

Comment: @ChrisBarrett That appears to have worked, thank you!